# PHP Looping through an array of results, only want to echo certain items once

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am looping through an array of results, however there are rows in the results with duplicate names. Is there a way to echo the name only once. The solution is probably trivial, but at the moment I'm stumped.

Here is the Code:

```
$service_query = $this->db->query('SELECT service_id, server_id, port, comment FROM services');

    foreach ($service_query->result() as $service)
    {
        $server_query = $this->db->query('SELECT server_id, name, host FROM servers WHERE server_id =' . $service->server_id);

        foreach ($server_query->result() as $server)
        {
            echo $server->name;
            echo $service->comment;
            echo $server->host;
            echo $service->port;
            echo '<br>';

        }
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
Mail Server   IMAP (Secure)    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:993
Mail Server   POP3 (Secure)    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:995
Mail Server   POP3             XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:110
Mail Server   IMAP             XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:143
Web Server    Apache           XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80
```

FYI I am using the codeigniter framework for this project.

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in your results. On what condition do you want to skip an item?

Comment: I would like to have "Mail Server" printed only once. I plan to use the server name as a header and group all the services under it with their status.

Comment: "I would like to have "Mail Server" printed only once." Which one? There are four of them, and they are all different - can you show us what your desired output looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, service_id, server_id, host, port, comment 
                              FROM services 
                              LEFT JOIN servers USING (server_id) 
                           ORDER BY servers.name');

$server_name = '';

foreach ($query->result() as $server)
{
    if($server_name != $server->name) {
        echo $server->name;
        $server_name = $server->name;
    } 
    else { echo '-/-/-' };

    echo $server->comment;
    echo $server->host;
    echo $server->port;
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Other then a missing semi-colon this worked perfectly. I originally tried to do this in one query but couldn't get it to work properly. Thanks for your help Oleg!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by querying the database for the $server before $service and echoing $server->name in the preceding loop. Here is my solution. Thanks to everyone for your quick answers.

```
$server_query = $this->db->query('SELECT server_id, name, host FROM servers');

    foreach ($server_query->result() as $server)
    {
        echo $server->name;

        $service_query = $this->db->query('SELECT service_id, server_id, port, comment FROM services  WHERE server_id =' . $server->server_id);

        foreach ($service_query->result() as $service)
        {
            echo $service->comment;
            echo $server->host;
            echo $service->port;
            echo '<br>';

        }
    }
```

Comment: It works! Although, you don't need to do more SQL queries, if you can do it in one query. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean the "Mail Server" data is duplicated? if so, consider to use the MySQL `DISTINCT` in your queries to remove duplicates, please see the sample [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Comment: No, I mean the name "Mail Server" is duplicated. I plan to use the server name as a header and group all the services under it with their status.

Comment: Ah I see, how about you change the logic to grab the server name first, then in the next looping you will grab the service data based on the server id, using this method, you will be able to have the server name as a header

Answer (score -1):

as i understand what you need. it would be like

Its in your SQL syntax

change it

```
'SELECT server_id, name, host FROM servers WHERE server_id =' . $service->server_id .' GROUP BY name'
```